# RSS parser + unicode decoding ( python )

Tags: python, unicode, rss

I have two questions :)

1. I am working on extension for my irc bot. It is supposed to check rss for new content and post it to channel. I am using feedparser. Only way I found is to store every new content to file and every few minutes download rss content and match it with content in file, which is in my opinion kinda weird. Is there some easy way how to check if there is new content in rss? Thx
2. When I am saving content to file, sometimes some parts are encoded by unicode ( special characters in czech language  ) - u"xxx". But I want to save them into file as utf8. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

1. RSS items usually have a GUID or a link associated with them. Use the GUID if present, otherwise the link to uniquely identify each item. You'll still have to keep track of which ones you've seen before, as the RSS format doesn't tell you what changed since last time. There really is no other way, I'm afraid.
2. To save `data`(a unicode object) in UTF-8, simply encode it when writing to the file:

   ```
   output.write(data.encode('utf8'))
   ```

Please do read the Joel Spolsky [article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html), to fully understand what encoding and decoding means.

Comment: 2. well this is exactly what i am doing, but the result isSecurityWorld.cz: AVG pÅedstavil svÃ¡ bezpeÄnostnÃ­ ÅeÅ¡enÃ­ ve verzi 2013 instead of SecurityWorld.cz: AVG představil svá bezpečnostní řešení ve verzi 2013 which is the correct version i get when i for example print it.

Comment: @user1505497: The data in your file is UTF-8 and you are trying to read it as latin1. The python code to write the data worked, it's the *loading* of the file that is failing.

Comment: latin1? when i try to encode it to latin1 i get UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u0159' in position 23: ordinal not in range(256). Well i am really confused about all those encodings..

Comment: @user1505497: Really, read the linked articles. I said you *wrote* UTF-8 and *read* latin1. That's something different than encoding to latin1 in the first place.